# mv - move dir with destination-dir having the same subdirs as source-dir

Tags: linux, shell, freebsd, mv

In FreeBSD (I suppose it works like Linux et al in this regard), I'd like to move `src_parent/mydir` to `dst_parent/mydir`. `dst_parent/mydir` already exists, and it contains some subdirs that's also contained by `src_parent/mydir`. We can assume that no *file* exists in both src and dst.

**Edit:** The source- and destination-directories are on different filesystems.

---

### Example:

`src_parent/dir`:

```
subdir1/
  file1b
subdir2/
  file2b
```

`dst_parent/dir`:

```
subdir1/
  file1a
subdir2/
  file2c
```

I'd like to `mv src_parent/dir dst_parent/dir`, so that `dst_parent/dir` ends up like this:

```
subdir1/
  file1a
  file1b
subdir2/
  file2b
  file2c
```

, which is the two dirs merged together. This is approx. the same behaviour as when moving files with GUI in f.x. MS Windows.

---

### Already tried:

I've unsuccessfully tried this:

```
$ mv -f /src_parent/mydir/* /dst_parent/mydir/*
mv: rename /src_parent/mydir/subdir1 to /dst_parent/mydir/subdir1: Directory not empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd link the files first and then remove the source dir:

```
 cd /src_parent
 find mydir -depth | cpio -pdlmv /dst_parent
```

check /dst_parent/mydir - if everything is fine:

```
 rm -rf /src_parent/mydir
```

Comment: Ah - if /src_parent and /dst_parent are on different filesystems, omit the cpio-option 'l'

Comment: I've never heard of `cpio` before. When should I use that instead of `cp` (when not working with archives) (I looked briefly in the manpages).

Comment: Other alternative: link the files with pax -r -w -l instead of cpio to the destination directory (assuming source and destination are on the same filesystem. Pleayse consult the man-page of pax for syntax details